# How to store an ARRAY in a Wordpress Custom Field?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, list

My array `$location` is empty. But this is very strange. The list (`$adresse, $lat, $long`) creates the variables `$lat` and `$long`. I know that, because they are entered in the `update_post_meta` fields. But the array does not work.
What am I doing wrong in creating the array? Does the list only work once?
Cheers,
Denis

PHP 7.2, Wordpress 5.02, WP User Frontend Pro Plugin WPUF 3.0.2

I tried the array like `$location[...]` but this does not work.
I tried to make the ARRAY static like

```
$location = array(      
    'latitude' => 'lat',
    'longitude' => 'long'
);
```

but that does not work :-(

This is my function code for Wordpress:

```
function update_GEOmyWP( $post_id ) {

if ( ! $post_id ) {
return;
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'gmw_update_post_location' ) ) {
return;
}

if ( isset( $_POST['aufnahmeort'] ) ) {

list( $adresse, $lat, $long ) = explode( '||', $_POST['aufnahmeort'] );

$location = array(      
    'latitude' => $lat,
    'longitude' => $long
);

if ( $adresse ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'newADDRESS', $adresse );
}
if ( $lat ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'newLAT', $lat );
}
if ( $long ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'newLONG', $long );
}
// I added this line to check if something is written in the meta field, but the field is empty.
if ( $location ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'newLOCATION', $location );
}

gmw_update_post_location( $post_id, $location );

}
}
add_action( 'wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'update_GEOmyWP' );
add_action( 'wpuf_edit_post_after_update', 'update_GEOmyWP' );
```

I would like to have an ARRAY of latitude and longitude.

I have an update:

I just loked into the database of wordpress in the `postmeta` table and under `newLOCATION` there is this THE ARRAY `a:2:{s:8:"latitude";s:12:" 50.7936389 ";s:9:"longitude";s:18:" 6.952259499999968";}` but why is it not in the metafield?

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you mean by it?

Comment: try to change $location array variable name with different one.

Comment: $location it is empty. There is nothing in the ARRAY.

Comment: What is the value of this ? `explode( '||', $_POST['aufnahmeort'] );` probably gives you array with one element

Comment: @dipmala Changing the name does not effect anything.

Comment: @PrabowoMurti The list works well.     $adresse = Drachenfels 1, 53639 Königswinter, Deutschland -     $lat =  50.6650948  -     $long =  7.210271599999942 - The original is     $_POST['aufnahmeort'] = Drachenfels 1, 53639 Königswinter, Deutschland||50.6650948||7.210271599999942.

Comment: I proposed to change the title of your question. It's not related with the empty array any longer

Comment: @PrabowoMurti You are right.

Answer (score 0):

> why is it not in the metafield

Did you mean that it's not shown in the custom field?

Your code above only does the job of saving the array value to the database. And as you already verified that value in the database (in the form of serialized array), it seems to work correctly.

Please check the code you use to display the custom field and see how you get the data from the database and show in the field. It's where you should debug.

Comment: Hello, yes, it is fine in the database.And it works fine now, I was irritaded by the custom field thing. Thanks.